# Flutter - Circle Avatar with Progress Bar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to achieve the below output.

[image: my_ques]

I am not getting any ideas on how can I do this. This isn't a border. I want to change the values depending on how much the user has completed his profile. If you have any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this library

```
percent_indicator: ^4.0.0
```

Here is example

```
CircularPercentIndicator(
                radius: 100.0,
                lineWidth: 10.0,
                percent: 0.2,
                center: const CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 45, // Image radius
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://resize.indiatvnews.com/en/resize/newbucket/715_-/2020/02/srk-1582818093.jpg'),
                ),
                progressColor: Colors.green,
              )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do these is by using [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator), this package get a widget and you can put your image in it(if it was not fit, try to use Stack).